# using sum with relation Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, orm

i have Model Material which has

```
 protected $with = ['costPrices'];

public function costPrices(){
    return $this->hasMany(CostPrice::class);
}
```

the table of cost_prices has multiple quantity

```
 //create_cost_prices_table
   Schema::create('cost_prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('material_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('supplier_id');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

i want  to get (insufficient materials ) in another way select all materials form materials table where sum of all quantities of cost_prices table < 3 and get me the resulted materials not the count

Comment: have a look at `whereHas`: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Comment: when i use `$materials = Material::whereHas('costPrices', function($q)
        {
            $q->havingRaw('SUM(quantity) > 4');

        })->get(); `
i get error 
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

You could fix your option with `whereHas()` by adding `select` and `groupBy`:

```
$materials = Material
    ::whereHas('costPrices', function($q) { 
        $q
            ->select('meterial_id')
            ->groupBy('material_id')
            ->havingRaw('SUM(quantity) > 4'); 
    })
    ->get();
```

Or use subquery:

For laravel 6.x:

```
$materials = Material
    ::addSelect([
        'cost_prices_sum' => CostPrice::selectRaw('sum(quantity)')->whereColumn('material_id', 'material.id')
    ])
    ->having('cost_prices_sum', '>', 4)
    ->get();
```

For laravel 5.x:

```
$materials = Material
    ::selectRaw('carts.*, (select sum(quantity) from cost_prices where cost_prices.matrerial_id = meterials.id) as cost_prices_sum')
    ->having('cost_prices_sum', '>', 4)
    ->get();
```

**UPDATE:** option with `whereHas()` is faster on a large number of rows.